# Run Raspbian "Wheezy" in QEMU on Windows

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, windows, qemu

Not sure if this is the right StackExchange forum to ask for that.

What I have is:

- kernel-qemu from http://xecdesign.com/downloads/linux-qemu/kernel-qemu
- 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img from http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/
- qemu-w32-setup-20140517.exe from http://qemu.weilnetz.de/

I tried for last couple of hours to start the Raspbian in QEMU on Windows. Changing the start command parameters, using qemu-system-arm.exe or qemu-system-armw.exe... The most I have done was to enter bash by init=/bin/bash and boot the Raspbian nearly to the shell, but didn't managed to boot it as far as it would on original RPi. Has anyone managed to run properly these versions? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out:

I needed to comment out one line in `/etc/ld.so.preload` file by adding # at the line beginning before starting Raspbian (problems with booting disappeared) and use:

```
qemu-system-armw.exe -M versatilepb -m 256 -cpu arm1176 -no-reboot -serial stdio -kernel kernel-qemu -hda rpi_disk.vmdk -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1"
```

command to start the QEMU. x64 version never worked, but x86 (32 bit) did the trick. Need to mention that QEMU from http://qemu.weilnetz.de/ (currently 1.5.3) is faster than the above given one.

Comment: Where did you make that edit? i see your using windows however i just get stuck in a boot loop you say you commented out a file in /etc/ld.so.preload so i would assume that is in the hda how did you edit it?

Comment: Don't remember exactly. I suppose I have mounted the image and then changed the file. Under Linux, Ubuntu. You do this once. Make backups!

Comment: i got it running forcing it into bash before all init.d files run :)

Comment: So you can edit the right file, you hacker!

Answer (score 0):

Also see this guide: http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/

It contains step by step instructions on how to comment out that line in the /etc/ld.so.preload file

Comment: dead link (403 forbidden)

Comment: Found it on WayBack Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150326230511/http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/

Comment: Someone also collected the howtos and kernels here: https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel