# Is there a Pi Simulator application for Debian?

Tags: raspbian, debian, emulation

I am still busy setting up a workstation/workbench for my PI, but in the mean time I would like to start getting to know some of it's internals, i.e. conversing with it. "How is your GPIO pin *n*, or please give be hardware system information.

I have Debian running in a VM on my Windows machine for this purpose, and to get to know Linux better.

Comment: I'm not aware of any BCM2835 hardware emulator: GPIO is very processor SOC (System on a Chip) dependent. try qemu. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/run-raspbian-wheezy-in-qemu-on-windows

Comment: Have you had a look on other questions tagged *emulation*? There might be some wisdom hidden there.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880833/emulating-the-raspberry-pi-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big reason it's hard to emulate on your likely-x86/x86_64 computer is that the Raspberry Pi uses an ARM CPU with the `armv7l` architecture. So, you'd have to emulate the processor architecture as well, which normal Virtual Machine platforms won't do.

However, there's actually a way to do this, explained [here (Raspberry Pi Emulation Using `qemu-user-static`)](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi/qemu-user-static) using [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU).

This will be a bit more difficult to get running under Windows, so, you might want to just set this up from inside the Debian VM you already created.

Answer (score 1):

No.

However if you plan to use Raspbian on the Pi just getting familiar with Debian will help.

Raspbian is a recompilation of Debian targeted at the old processor used on most Pis.

Try a tutorial on command line tools such as copy, rename, dir; editors such as nano, vi etc.  They all work the same on the Pi and you will need to use them occasionally.